# How do I open the app through clicking the notification bar?

Tags: android, notifications

I am trying to open my app by clicking on the app's notification bar. The coding is as below. I've tried to add pendingintent but not sure which format it would use.

```
    
        public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "channel1";
    
        public static final String ACTION_PREVIOUS = "actionprevious";
        public static final String ACTION_PLAY = "actionplay";
        public static final String ACTION_NEXT = "actionnext";
    
        public static Notification notification;
    
        public static void createNotification(Context context, TrackModel trackModel, int playbutton, int pos, int size){
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
    
                NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
                MediaSessionCompat mediaSessionCompat = new MediaSessionCompat(context, "tag");
                Bitmap icon =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.img1);
    
    
    
                notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,CHANNEL_ID)
    
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_music)
                        .setContentTitle(trackModel.getName())
                        .setLargeIcon(icon)
                        .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                        .setShowWhen(false)
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .build();
                notificationManagerCompat.notify(1, notification);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

add *.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)* to your notification builder

```
val newIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
newIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

val pendingIntent = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, newIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
    } else {
        PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, newIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a Pending Intent for your Notification so that when you click you notification it opens you app:

[Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/navigation)